# RXJS Convert Observable to boolean

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hello I'm trying to write function like this

```
 verify(){
    return this.http.post(environment.api+'recaptcha/verify',{
      token : this.token
    }).pipe(map(res=>res.json()));
  }
```

i want use it as boolean like

```
if(this.verfiy()) { do something}
```

how , Now i must subscript first and handle data

Comment: Regardless of using rxjs or not, javascript itself is full of async operations.

Answer (score 4):

Since your HTTP call is asynchronous you will have to wait for its response. 
Try this:

```
this.verify().subscribe(
   res => {
       if (res) {
           // do something
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: so i have to make subscript and wait it in component

Comment: That's the idea yes :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
verify(){
    return this.http.post(blah)
        .pipe(
            map((res: any) => res.json()),
            filter(json => json)
        );
}
```

The filter will only return if the json was not falsy.

So then you can do this:

```
service.verify().subscribe(()=>{
    // This code only will fire when the json was not falsy
    console.log("We verified it");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `verify` function to subscribe and determine the `boolean` based on the http response, `Subscribe` inside your verify function instead of pipe..

```
verify(){
    this.http.post(environment.api+'recaptcha/verify',{
      token : this.token
    }).subscribe(res=> {

                        //do your logic to return boolean
                        return res.json();
                       });
  }
```

Comment: it's not return a data as json it's return data like that "Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …} closed: true destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …} isStopped: true syncErrorThrowable: true syncErrorThrown: false syncErrorValue: null _parent: null _parentSubscription: null _parents: null _subscriptions: null __proto__: Subscription"